# jQuery Validation Plugin - message box display

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using the jQuery Validation Plugin to successfully display messages in the upper right corner of the browser window. The message also remains in view when the page is scrolled. What I am having trouble with is displaying the initial message in view when the page has already been scrolled beyond where the absolute top right corner can be seen. At that point, the message comes into view as soon as the page is scrolled but I would also like the message to display in view as soon as the field is invalidated.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/site.css" />
<script src="jquery/jquery.min-latest.js"></script>
<script src="jquery/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery/jquery.validate.dateUS.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    // attach Validate plugin to form
    $("#form").validate();

});

//scroll the message box to the top offset of browser's scroll bar
$(window).scroll(function(){
    $('.error').animate({
        top:$(window).scrollTop()+"px" },{queue: false, duration: 0
    });
});
</script>
```

This is *site.css*:

```
label.error {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; right: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: small;
    width: 150px;
    border: 1px solid;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
    color: #D63301;
    background-color: #FFCCBA;
}

.error {
    background-color: #FFCCBA;
}
```

Comment: Screen shot or clarification of the problem please?

Comment: You left out the relevant HTML.